# How to display hyphen in uilabel?

Tags: ios, objective-c

How to display hyphen with `UILabel` like this, **- A I origine -** , Here I use the string appending method. I get this type of output **- À l'origine de la guerre -**. But I want display hyphen before the starting point of text and display hyphen after 10 charatcers.

I was searched but i can't get valied source. kindly give any suggestion if you know.

```
 NSString *tempStr = @" - ";
    tempStr = [tempStr stringByAppendingString:NSLocalizedString(@"OriginallyWar", @"")];
    tempStr = [tempStr stringByAppendingString:@" -"];
    [headingLabel setText:tempStr];
    [headingLabel setFont:MRSEAVES_BOLD(17)];
```

Comment: you must try attributedString

Comment: use NSMutableString instead NSString.

Answer (score 0):

Use NSMutableString and insert characters,

```
[yourString insertString:@"-" atIndex:10];
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using StoryBoard directly set it to the text property on Attribute inspector. Put 10 empty spaces after the end of character and the -.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this code

```
  NSString *inputString = @"OriginallyWarDFdfsdfdDFSDfdsfdsfDFdsfadsfawerdsaf";
  NSMutableString *localizedInputString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:NSLocalizedString(inputString, @"")];

  int numberOfCharacters = localizedInputString.length;
  int numberOf10s = (numberOfCharacters/10 + 1);
  int numberOfCharactersToBeInserted = 0;

  for (int i = 1; i < numberOf10s; i++) {
    int characterIndex = (i * 10) + numberOfCharactersToBeInserted;
    if (i == (numberOf10s - 1) && numberOfCharacters % 10 == 0) {
      [localizedInputString insertString:@" -" atIndex:characterIndex];
      numberOfCharactersToBeInserted = 2 * i;
    } else {
      [localizedInputString insertString:@" - " atIndex:characterIndex];
      numberOfCharactersToBeInserted = 3 * i;
    }
  }
  if (numberOfCharacters == 0) {
    [localizedInputString insertString:@"-" atIndex:0];
  } else {
    [localizedInputString insertString:@"- " atIndex:0];
  }

  NSLog(@"localizedInputString : %@", localizedInputString);
```

Answer (score 0):

try using NSMutableString

```
NSString *tempStr = @" - ";
tempStr = [tempStr stringByAppendingString:NSLocalizedString(@"OriginallyWar", @"")];
NSMutableString *tempStrMutable=[[NSMutableString alloc]initWithString:tempStr];
[tempStrMutable insertString:@"-" atIndex:10];
[headingLabel setText:tempStrMutable];
```